# I am trying to create a UIView/ScrollView in which showing data in Tabular form in iOS just like a pdf preview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pdf, core-text

I want to create this type of output as mentioned in image[image]

Above view is repeated as much time as array has the users so it may be 10 20 so pdf pages can be multiple.
I have tried coretext Mgazine tutorial
http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app

also used this with single column
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = self.indentX+20;
        paragraphStyle.headIndent = self.indentX;
        paragraphStyle.alignment = self.aligment;

but not able to create this type of output. Please share if any have a logic to implement this.